# Use different .ini file for alembic.ini

Tags: python, pyramid, alembic

I'm attempting to configure SQLAlchemy Alembic for my Pyramid project and I want to use my developement.ini (or production.ini) for the configuration settings for Alembic. Is it possible to specify the .ini file I wish to use anywhere within Alembic?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just specify `alembic -c /some/path/to/another.ini` when running alembic commands. You could even put the `[alembic]` section in your development.ini and production.ini files and just `alembic -c production.ini upgrade head`.

Comment: Just as an addition, you MUST put the `-c /some/path/to/another.ini` BEFORE the commands or it gets confused.

Comment: Also one might need to chnage the `script_location` in the `alembic.ini` as well

Answer (score 1):

in many cases you can also use one shared alembic.ini and dynamically compute some parts somewhere else and interpolate them into the alembic.ini via `%(VARIABLE)s` replacements. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190497/2536029 for a complete description.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your albemic/env.py file to take variables like the DB url from your other config. I have a config.py that ingests from environment specific ini files and I use this to define the database url, which my albemic env file then uses.