# Is it possible to store the alembic connect string outside of alembic.ini?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Alembic with SQLAlchemy. With SQLAlchemy, I tend to follow a pattern where I don't store the connect string with the versioned code. Instead I have file `secret.py` that contains any confidential information. I throw this filename in my `.gitignore` so it doesn't end up on GitHub.

This pattern works fine, but now I'm getting into using Alembic for migrations. It appears that I cannot hide the connect string. Instead in `alembic.ini`, you place the connect string as a [configuration parameter](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file):

```
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembi
```

I fear I'm going to accidentally commit a file with username/password information for my database. I'd rather store this connect string in a single place and avoid the risk of accidentally committing it to version control.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 118):

I had the very same problem yesterday and found a following solution to work.
I do the following in `alembic/env.py`:

```
# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# this will overwrite the ini-file sqlalchemy.url path
# with the path given in the config of the main code
import config as ems_config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', ems_config.config.get('sql', 'database'))
```

`ems_config` is an external module that holds my configuration data.

`config.set_main_option(...)` essentially overwrites the `sqlalchemy.url` key in the `[alembic]` section of the `alembic.ini` file. In my configuration I simply leave it black.

Comment: I think `alembic.config` is an API for internal use and should not be used when using alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/config.html "this section discusses the internal API of Alembic as regards internal configuration constructs. "

Answer (score 96):

The simplest thing I could come up with to avoid commiting my user/pass  was to a) add in interpolation strings to the `alembic.ini` file, and b) set these interpolation values in `env.py`

**alembic.ini**

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://%(DB_USER)s:%(DB_PASS)s@35.197.196.146/nozzle-website
```

**env.py**

```
import os

from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# here we allow ourselves to pass interpolation vars to alembic.ini
# fron the host env
section = config.config_ini_section
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_USER", os.environ.get("DB_USER"))
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_PASS", os.environ.get("DB_PASS"))

...
```

Comment: this worked for me and seems easier than the top answer - any downsides?

Comment: As env.py now depends on env vars being correctly set you may want to put in some defensive coding and provide a helpful "usage" message if DB_USER or DB_PASS are not set.

Comment: By far the most up to date solution. By now you a probably setting passwords in an protected .env file anyway and load it with dotenv. So it only makes sense to reuse this env variables.
You also probably don't need "devensive coding" if you just write os.environ["DB_USER"], because the resulting key errors are already very explicit.

Comment: Seems to be hard when there is '@' character in the password

Comment: @npk You should URL-encode the password in such case (or, really, always). https://www.urlencoder.io/python/

Comment: Works great! Notice the `s` after the interpolated values

Answer (score 41):

[Alembic documentation](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.get_x_argument) suggests using `create_engine` with the database URL (instead of [modifying sqlalchemy.url in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256675/12663)).

Also you should modify run_migrations_offline to use the new URL. Allan Simon has [an example](http://allan-simon.github.io/blog/posts/python-alembic-with-environment-variables/) on his blog, but in summary, modify env.py to:

1. Provide a shared function to get the URL somehow (here it comes from the command line):

   ```
   def get_url():
       url = context.get_x_argument(as_dictionary=True).get('url')
       assert url, "Database URL must be specified on command line with -x url=<DB_URL>"
       return url
   ```
2. Use the URL in offline mode:

   ```
   def run_migrations_offline():
       ...
       url = get_url()
       context.configure(
           url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True)
       ...
   ```
3. Use the URL in online mode by using `create_engine` instead of `engine_from_config`:

   ```
   def run_migrations_online():
       ...
       connectable = create_engine(get_url())
       with connectable.connect() as connection:
       ...
   ```

Comment: This can be combined with https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#sharing-a-connection-with-a-series-of-migration-commands-and-environments which makes it a great answer!

Comment: I had to add in env.py file this line `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

Comment: For async use case (where the alembic was initialized like: `alembic init -t async migrations`), in **async def run_migrations_online()** set `connectable = AsyncEngine(create_engine(get_url()))`

Answer (score 11):

So what appears to work is reimplementing engine creation in `env.py`, which is apparently a place for doing this kind of customizing Instead of using the sqlalchemy connect string in the ini:

```
engine = engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
            prefix='sqlalchemy.',
           poolclass=pool.NullPool)
```

You can replace and specify your own engine configuration:

```
import store
engine = store.engine
```

Indeed the docs [seems to imply](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file) this is ok:

> sqlalchemy.url - A URL to connect to the database via SQLAlchemy. This key is in fact only referenced within the env.py file that is specific to the “generic” configuration; a file that can be customized by the developer. A multiple database configuration may respond to multiple keys here, or may reference other sections of the file.

Comment: With latest alembic (0.8.1), this will only affect the 'online' mode. `run_migrations_offline` would also need changing to use a different database URL.

Answer (score 7):

## env.py:

```
from alembic.config import Config

alembic_cfg = Config()
alembic_cfg.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", getenv('PG_URI'))
```

https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/config.html

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a while how to manage this for mutli-databases

Here is what I did. I have two databases : **logs** and **ohlc**

According to the [doc](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-an-environment),
I have setup the alembic like that

```
alembic init --template multidb
```

### alembic.ini

```
databases = logs, ohlc
[logs]
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@localhost/logs
[ohlc]
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@localhost/ohlc
```

### env.py

```
[...]
# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# overwrite alembic.ini db urls from the config file
settings_path = os.environ.get('SETTINGS')
if settings_path:
    with open(settings_path) as fd:
        settings = conf.load(fd, context=os.environ) # loads the config.yml
    config.set_section_option("ohlc", "sqlalchemy.url", settings["databases"]["ohlc"])
    config.set_section_option("logs", "sqlalchemy.url", settings["databases"]["logs"])
else:
    logger.warning('Environment variable SETTINGS missing - use default alembic.ini configuration')
[...]
```

### config.yml

```
databases:
    logs: postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@127.0.0.1:5432/logs
    ohlc: postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@127.0.0.1:5432/ohlc
```

**usage**

```
SETTINGS=config.yml alembic upgrade head
```

Hope it can helps !

Answer (score 4):

In the case of **MultiDB** settings (the same for SingleDB), you can use ***config.set_section_option('section_name', 'variable_name', 'db_URL')*** to modify the values of the database URL in the alembic.ini file.

For example:

**alembic.init**

```
[engine1]
sqlalchemy.url = 

[engine2]
sqlalchemy.url =
```

Then,

**env.py**

```
config = context.config

config.set_section_option('engine1', 'sqlalchemy.url', os.environ.get('URL_DB1'))
config.set_section_option('engine2', 'sqlalchemy.url', os.environ.get('URL_DB2'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I was bumping into this problem as well since we're running our migrations from our local machines. My solution is to put environment sections in the `alembic.ini` which stores the database config (minus the credentials):

```
[local]
host = localhost
db = dbname

[test]
host = x.x.x.x
db = dbname

[prod]
host = x.x.x.x
db = dbname
```

Then I put the following in the `env.py` so the user can pick their environment and be prompted for the credentials:

```
from alembic import context
from getpass import getpass

...

envs = ['local', 'test', 'prod']

print('Warning: Do not commit your database credentials to source control!')
print(f'Available migration environments: {", ".join(envs)}')

env = input('Environment: ')

if env not in envs:
    print(f'{env} is not a valid environment')
    exit(0)

env_config = context.config.get_section(env)
host = env_config['host']
db = env_config['db']

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass()
connection_string = f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{db}'

context.config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', connection_string)
```

You should store your credentials in a password manager that the whole team has access to, or whatever config/secret store you have available. Though, with this approach the password is exposed to your local clip board - an even better approach would be to have `env.py` directly connect to your config/secret store API and pull out the username/password directly but this adds a third party dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I want to use SQLAlchemy and redshift as database.

Also, I do not want to set up same configuation files for both of them.

So, I decided to use .env like Laravel.

To set up.

Firstly, install python-dotenv and other staffs like this.

```
pip install python-dotenv alembic psycopg2-binary SQLAlchemy sqlalchemy-redshift
```

In alembic.ini file, I kept blank like this.

```
#sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname
sqlalchemy.url =
```

In env.py, I added following.
The point is that you should put these before function.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
dialect = "redshift+psycopg2://"
url = dialect + os.getenv("REDSHIFT_USER") + ":" + os.getenv("REDSHIFT_PW") + "@" + os.getenv("REDSHIFT_HOST") + "/" + os.getenv("REDSHIFT_DATABASE")
config.set_main_option( 'sqlalchemy.url', url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to **create a template alembic.ini.dist file** and to track it with your versionned code, while ignoring alembic.ini in your VCS.

Do not add any confidential information in alembic.ini.dist:

```
sqlalchemy.url = ...
```

When deploying your code to a platform, copy alembic.ini.dist to alembic.ini (this one won't be tracked by your VCS) and modify alembic.ini with the platform's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

[As Doug T. said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22179047/1709587) you can edit env.py to provide URL from somewhere else than ini file. Instead of creating new engine you can pass an additional `url` argument to the `engine_from_config` function (kwargs are later merged to options taken from ini file). In that case you could e.g. store encrypted password in ini file and decrypt it in runtime by passphrase stored in ENV variable.

```
connectable = engine_from_config(                 
    config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
    prefix='sqlalchemy.',                         
    poolclass=pool.NullPool,                      
    url=some_decrypted_endpoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that worked for me was to use `set_main_option` and leave the `sqlalchemy.url =` blank in `alembic.ini`

```py
from config import settings

config.set_main_option(
    "sqlalchemy.url", settings.database_url.replace("postgres://", "postgresql+asyncpg://", 1))
```

> sttings is a class in config file that I use to get variables in env file check this [os.environ.get() does not return the Environment Value in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978739/os-environ-get-does-not-return-the-environment-value-in-windows/72916628#72916628) for more detail, another option is to use `os.environ.get` but make sure that you export the varibale to prevent errors like [sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776619/sqlalchemy-exc-argumenterror-could-not-parse-rfc1738-url-from-string/72916860#72916860)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of *TomDotTom* I came up with this solution

Edit the `env.py` file with this

```py
config = context.config
config.set_section_option("alembic", "sqlalchemy.url",
                          os.environ.get("DB_URL", config.get_section_option("alembic", "sqlalchemy.url"))) # type: ignore
```

This will override the `sqlalchemy.url` option from the `alembic` section with `DB_URL` environment variable if such environment variable exists, otherwise will use what else is in the `alembic.ini` file

Then I can run the migrations pointing to another database like this

```
DB_URL=driver://user:pass@host:port/dbname alembic upgrade head
```

And keep using `alembic upgrade head` during my development flow

Answer (score -1):

In `env.py` just add

```py
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', os.environ['DB_URL'])
```

after

```py
config = context.config
```

like

```py
config = context.config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', os.environ['DB_URL'])
```

and then execute like that:

```sh
DB_URL="mysql://atuamae:de4@127.0.0.1/db" \
  alembic upgrade head
```

Answer (score -3):

I've tried all the answer here, but not working. Then I try to deal by myself, as below:

.ini file:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration files
file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(year)d_%%(month).2d_%%(day).2d_%%(hour).2d_%%(minute).2d_%%(second).2d

# timezone to use when rendering the date
# within the migration file as well as the filename.
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
#truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; this defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat alembic/versions

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

databases = auth_engine


[auth_engine]
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@{}:{}/auth_db

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

.env file(it is in the root folder of my project):

```
DB_USER='root'
DB_PASS='12345678'
DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
DB_PORT='3306'
```

env.py file:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import os
import re
import sys
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

DB_USER = os.getenv("DB_USER")
DB_PASS = os.getenv("DB_PASS")
DB_HOST = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
DB_PORT = os.getenv("DB_PORT")

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# gather section names referring to different
# databases.  These are named "engine1", "engine2"
# in the sample .ini file.
db_names = config.get_main_option('databases')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../"))
from db_models.auth_db import auth_db_base

target_metadata = {
    'auth_engine': auth_db_base.auth_metadata
}


# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    engines = {}
    for name in re.split(r',\s*', db_names):
        engines[name] = rec = {}
        section = context.config.get_section(name)
        url = section['sqlalchemy.url'].format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT)
        section['sqlalchemy.url'] = url
        rec['url'] = url
        # rec['url'] = context.config.get_section_option(name, "sqlalchemy.url")

    for name, rec in engines.items():
        print("Migrating database %s" % name)
        file_ = "%s.sql" % name
        print("Writing output to %s" % file_)
        with open(file_, 'w') as buffer:
            context.configure(url=rec['url'], output_buffer=buffer,
                              target_metadata=target_metadata.get(name),
                              compare_type=True,
                              compare_server_default=True
                              )

            with context.begin_transaction():
                context.run_migrations(engine_name=name)


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    engines = {}
    for name in re.split(r',\s*', db_names):
        engines[name] = rec = {}
        section = context.config.get_section(name)
        url = section['sqlalchemy.url'].format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT)
        section['sqlalchemy.url'] = url
        rec['engine'] = engine_from_config(
            section,
            prefix='sqlalchemy.',
            poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    for name, rec in engines.items():
        engine = rec['engine']
        rec['connection'] = conn = engine.connect()
        rec['transaction'] = conn.begin()

    try:
        for name, rec in engines.items():
            print("Migrating database %s" % name)
            context.configure(
                connection=rec['connection'],
                upgrade_token="%s_upgrades" % name,
                downgrade_token="%s_downgrades" % name,
                target_metadata=target_metadata.get(name),
                compare_type=True,
                compare_server_default=True
            )
            context.run_migrations(engine_name=name)

        for rec in engines.values():
            rec['transaction'].commit()
    except:
        for rec in engines.values():
            rec['transaction'].rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        for rec in engines.values():
            rec['connection'].close()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Wish can help someone else.

Comment: This is wrong and dangerous on too many levels to untangle, so I'm just going to point out that going three folders up to tamper with the syspath should never ever happen.

Comment: As Alex said, the path tampering. But also the post with several files and no written clue where in the code is the solution or in which is based :)