# os.environ.get() does not return the Environment Value in windows?

Tags: python, environment-variables, slack

I already set SLACK_TOKEN environment Variable. But  `"SLACK_TOKEN=os.environ.get('SLACK_TOKEN')"` is returning "None".
The type of **SLACK_TOKEN** is **NoneType**. I think os.environ.get not fetching value of environment variable. so rest of the code is not executing.

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient


SLACK_TOKEN= os.environ.get('SLACK_TOKEN') #returning None
print(SLACK_TOKEN) # None
print(type(SLACK_TOKEN)) # NoneType class

slack_client = SlackClient(SLACK_TOKEN)
print(slack_client.api_call("api.test")) #{'ok': True}
print(slack_client.api_call("auth.test")) #{'ok': False, 'error': 'not_authed'}


def list_channels():
    channels_call = slack_client.api_call("channels.list")
    if channels_call['ok']:
        return channels_call['channels']
    return None

def channel_info(channel_id):
    channel_info = slack_client.api_call("channels.info", channel=channel_id)
    if channel_info:
        return channel_info['channel']
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    channels = list_channels()
    if channels:
        print("Channels: ")
        for c in channels:
            print(c['name'] + " (" + c['id'] + ")")
            detailed_info = channel_info(c['id'])
            if detailed_info:
                print(detailed_info['latest']['text'])
    else:
        print("Unable to authenticate.") #Unable to authenticate
```

Comment: Are you sure you've set the environment correctly. What happens if you `echo "$SLACK_TOKEN"` in a shell?

Comment: A `.get(..)` usually returns `None` if the key cannot be found. So it means there is no `SLACK_TOKEN` in the `environ`.

Comment: If you set it in Windows, you must restart the shell, or open a new one, to have it show up. Existing shells will not get newly set environment variables.

Comment: Really?! How "lame"?!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Not really "lame"; it guarantees that the environments you've opened already have a consistent state. Linux shells work the same way.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue.I fixed it by removing quotes from the values.
Example:
I created a local.env file wherein I stored my secret key values :

```
*local.env:*
export SLACK_TOKEN=xxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz

*settings.py:*
SLACK_TOKEN = os.environ.get('SLACK_TOKEN')
```

In your python terminal or console,run the command : `*source local.env*`

****Involve local.env in gitignore.Make sure you dont push it to git as you have to safeguard your information.

This is applicable only to the local server.Hope this helps.Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks i was facing problem because i had not set environment variable properly

Comment: make sure you are running source in the same tab/window where you are running the app

Comment: ```source .env``` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You can use `python-dotenv` package to load the env vars in python. Install the package with:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Import it in the `.py` file using

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

Finally call the `load_dotenv()` function before trying to access the variables with `os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR_NAME')`

Comment: it worked I had to use above two lines in same file where I was using environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I write **wrong content** in env file:

```
SLACK_TOKEN=xxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

I forgot `export` befor it, the **correct** should be:

```
export SLACK_TOKEN=xxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `config` file to get the env vars without using export,
in the env file store varibale normally

`.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:dina@localhost/mysenseai
```

Then create a config file that will be used to store the env variable like so

`config.py`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    database_url: str

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'


settings = Settings()
```

than you can use it that way

```py
from config import settings

url = settings.database_url
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the variable SLACK_TOKEN in the windows command prompt you will be able to access it in the same instance of that command prompt not anywhere including Powershell and the git bash. Be careful with that
whenever you want to run that python script, consider running it in the same command prompt where you declared those variables
you can always check if the variable exists in the cmd by running echo `%SLACK_TOKEN%` if it does not exists the cmd will return `%SLACK_TOKEN%`