# In flask, os.environ.get() return None

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I want to get th variable `TOKEN` from my environment in Flask

config.py:

```
*config.py:*
TOKEN = os.environ.get('TOKEN')
```

So i `export TOKEN=666`
Then:

```
$ sudo python3 manage.py shell
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('TOKEN')
>>> quit()
```

It return None.

After i read this -->[os.environ.get() does not return the Environment Value in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978739/os-environ-get-does-not-return-the-environment-value-in-windows)

```
*local.env:*
export TOKEN=666

*config.py:*
TOKEN = os.environ.get('TOKEN')
```

and

```
$ source local.env
$ echo $TOKEN
666
$ sudo python3 manage.py shell
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('TOKEN')
>>> quit()
```

so as :`$ sudo python3 manage.py runserver`

if i `print(TOKEN)`, it return `NONE`

But if i run python directly:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ
>>> os.environ.get('TOKEN')
'666'
```

and if i set `os.environ[TOKEN] = '666'` directly...i can't keep it secretly:(

Comment: are you sure that `sudo` inherits from environment? I'd say that it _doesn't_

Comment: cross site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337819/how-to-export-variable-for-use-with-sudo. Use `sudo -E` to propagate variables

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre oh I know it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` does not propagate environment variables unless explicitly configured to do so.

Use `sudo --preserve-env` or `sudo -E` to avoid this.